# Visual Studio 2012 unable to load project with wildcard and property ItemGroup include

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

i have a simple .vcxproj File which looks like this:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyProjectName>sample_project</MyProjectName>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="..\$(MyProjectName)\*.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

Visual Studio 2012 is unable to load this project and states "...vcxproj : error  : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Running MSBuild on the command line will build the project just fine as expected, i.e. it will compile all .cpp files in ..\sample_project.

These two variants will work in Visual Studio:

```
<ClCompile Include="..\sample_project\*.cpp" />

<ClCompile Include="..\$(MyProjectName)\main.cpp" />
```

Just the combination of a wildcard and a property fails.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio, and if is there a workaround for this? I found some stuff on SO regarding getting advanced wildcards to work in MSBuild, but nothing about that a simple construct such as this - which works in MSBuild without a problem - doesn't work in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It surely is a bug, and affects VS2010 as well. This bug, along with a couple of others, just renders clear how the VS development team lacks the slightest notion of _how XML actually works_. My recommendation is to simply avoid messing too much with the project file if the VS IDE must be used at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Sources>*.c</Sources>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- This doesn't work... -->
    <!-- <ClCompile Include="$(Sources)" /> -->
    <!-- ...but this does. -->
    <ClCompile Include="$(Sources);Dummy" Exclude="Dummy" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

After throwing away the entire project file directory and rebuilding it per hand from scratch it turns out that the file Visual Studio had a problem with was not the MSBuild project file itself, but the .filters file. It seems like the filtering in Visual Studio is unable to work with this kind of item list. Having no .filters file will allow Visual Studio to open the project and everything works fine. But providing any kind of .filters file, or even trying to add a filter in the IDE itself will lead to an error message and Visual Studio will refuse to work with the project until the filters file is deleted and the IDE is restarted.

This bug is kinda annoying, i hope my struggle will help anyone who runs into the same issue.